# Resource on phase transition in MAXCUT problems

Tags: sat, max-cut, phase-transition, random-k-sat, max2sat

Could anyone suggest reading materials on phase transition in MAXCUT problems other than [1]? Thanks.

Ref:

1. Coppersmith, Don, David Gamarnik, Mohammad Taghi Hajiaghayi, and Gregory B. Sorkin. "Random MAX SAT, random MAX CUT, and their phase transitions." In SODA, pp. 364-373. 2003.